# Usage of the Variable inside the select-value clause to traverse through the XML path

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am trying to fetch the XML value based on a condition, if the variable value matches the value of the XML path mentioned then to obtain the value of its own sub elements.
The Input XML looks like below

```
<ns1:productSpecificationFullDTO xmlns:ns1="http://www.micros.com/creations/core/domain/dto/v1p0/full" xmlns:ns2="http://www.micros.com/creations/core/domain/dto/v1p0/simple">
<ns1:product>
    <ns1:name>Test Component 1</ns1:name>
    <ns1:parent>false</ns1:parent>
</ns1:product>
<ns1:product>
    <ns1:name>Test Component 2</ns1:name>
    <ns1:parent>false</ns1:parent>
</ns1:product>
<ns1:specification>
    <ns1:name>Test Component 1</ns1:name>
    <ns1:parent>false</ns1:parent>
    <ns1:Labeling>
        <ns1:mainProductTitle>Test1</ns1:ns1:mainProductTitle>
    </ns1:Labeling>
</ns1:specification>
<ns1:specification>
    <ns1:name>Test Component 2</ns1:name>
    <ns1:parent>false</ns1:parent>
    <ns1:Labeling>
        <ns1:mainProductTitle>Test2</ns1:ns1:mainProductTitle>
    </ns1:Labeling>
</ns1:specification>
```

My XSLT Definition is below

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="http://www.micros.com/creations/core/domain/dto/v1p0/full" xmlns:ns2="http://www.micros.com/creations/core/domain/dto/v1p0/simple" exclude-result-prefixes="ns1 ns1">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <ItemDetails>
        <Items>
            <!-- Food section start here -->
            <xsl:for-each select="/ns1:productSpecificationFullDTO/ns1:product/ns1:parent[text() != 'true']/../ns1:name[text() != 'Parent']/..">
                <xsl:variable name="subItem" select="ns1:name/text()"/>
                <Item>
                    <name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$subItem"/>
                    </name>
                    <LongDescription>
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(ns1:productSpecificationFullDTO/ns1:specification/ns1:parent[text() != 'true']/../ns1:name[text() = '''$subItem''']/../ns1:Labeling/ns1:mainProductTitle/text())"/>
                    </LongDescription>
                </Item>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Items>
    </ItemDetails>
</xsl:template>
```

The output is as below

```
<Items>
  <Item>
     <name>Test Component 1</name>
     <LongDescription/>
  </Item>
  <Item>
     <name>Test Component 2</name>
     <LongDescription/>
  </Item>
```

Desired Output is

```
<Items>
  <Item>
     <name>Test Component 1</name>
     <LongDescription>Test1<LongDescription/>
  </Item>
  <Item>
     <name>Test Component 2</name>
     <LongDescription>Test2<LongDescription/>
  </Item>
```

As Seen above i'm unable to fetch the value of that variable's sub element.
Please advise, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this solves what you are trying to accomplish, simplifying your XPath expressions and using a key to get to the linked descriptions.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:ns1="http://www.micros.com/creations/core/domain/dto/v1p0/full" 
  xmlns:ns2="http://www.micros.com/creations/core/domain/dto/v1p0/simple" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="ns1 ns2">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:key name="keySpec" match="ns1:specification" use="ns1:name"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <ItemDetails>
          <Items>
              <!-- Food section start here -->
              <xsl:for-each select="/ns1:productSpecificationFullDTO/ns1:product[not(ns1:parent='true') and not(ns1:name='Parent')]">
                  <Item>
                      <name>
                          <xsl:value-of select="ns1:name"/>
                      </name>
                      <LongDescription>
                          <xsl:value-of select="key('keySpec',ns1:name)/ns1:Labeling/ns1:mainProductTitle"/>
                      </LongDescription>
                  </Item>
              </xsl:for-each>
          </Items>
      </ItemDetails>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qjt5Sw/1

Comment: Hi, Thanks this worked for me. appreciate it